# Is my data "normal enough" for ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, anova

I am wondering if it is valid to use ANOVA to test for differences in this data. My dataset is a several years worth of retail transactions, the price and month of each transaction. Theoretically I could observe fractional values, but in reality the data is highly concentrated at each $5 mark. Does that create a situation that would invalidate ANOVA results? If so, is there a better test that I could use to find differences in pairwise comparisons of different months?

The histograms below show an example of my data with the observed price($) along the x-axis. I am using the date labels as my groups. After plotting the CDFs for each of my pairwise comparisons, I am finding that the ANOVA p-values do not align with my visual assessment.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to compare the time series collected in April to the time series collected in May?

Comment: @Dave not time series, but i am trying to compare the price distributions.

Comment: Those distributions are perfectly fine for ANOVA.  But ANOVA is unlikely to address any question of interest or utility in this context and the p-values are going to be wrong due to temporal correlations.  What *kinds* of differences interest you?  What do you really need to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are also independence and variance homogeneity assumptions. A major problem here could be dependence. Your data are surely not normal and there are some strange patterns, but the non-normality doesn't seem to be of a kind that grossly invalidates the ANOVA. However the two distributions you show are so similar in the details that this looks out of order for two *independent* datasets from the same distribution, normal or not (probably there's some explanation for this in the way the data were obtained), and this will in all likelihood invalidate the ANOVA.